# My site got SSL from letsencrypt but content needs editing to reflect transition from http to https

Tags: ssl, https

I just installed SSL certificate from letsencrypt strictly following [these instruction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) on my digitalocean server.
Now my site looks like [this](https://worddetail.org/). What can I do to revert changes I just made on my ubuntu 14.04 machine?

Comment: @mikewhatever - to me this is not exactly offtopic but valid question just landed in wrong SE area, it should be moved to area where simple http coding mistakes helped to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem had been caused not by Ubuntu. When you installed SSL certificate, you have only secured connection between your server and user's browser. That's only first step. Now you have to do next step - go around every single page on your site and change sourcing from (insecure) http protocol to (secure) https one. Otherwise browser on user's side "thinks" it fetches insecure content from sites different than your secure URL points to.

To do that, you have to traverse whole file/directory hierarchy of your site, and change every http:// prefix with https:// prefix. You have to split that work into two parts:

1. In this round you have to change everything local, i.e. starting from http://worddetail.org to https://worddetail.org -- all these resources are in your domain and hence you can check whether that content is present, and what to do if it is not (e.g. when it is generated on the fly by some internal engine or script).
2. In this round you have to change everything remote, all other http:// prefixes with https:// prefixes. When you do this step, make sure every resource is present at new https:// address. You can do that by simply typing that new string into browser's URL field and check whether you get 404 error or something actual starts to be fetched. You can actually skip these checks with risk that some elements won't be found at new URL, and hence parts of site won't work anyway. In case when some elements are http-only, you will need to find new location at any other public service, use Google if nothing else helps.